# Loading multiple modules in single WPF thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I have an application in which I want to load multiple WPF applications as Modules. Here each modules should come up as a windows but still be able to access multiple modules at any given moment. If I create separate UI threads than some of the modules crash reporting exception that cannot access UI object from different thread than the one who created it. So, is it possible to load multiple modules in a single UI thread?

Comment: Nope.  UI elements are thread centric.  They have to load on the UI.  Better to use the MVVM pattern with templates to throttle UI loading speeds.

Answer (score 1):

> So, is it possible to load multiple modules in a single UI thread?

Yes, you can load each "module" into the main UI thread.  Provided each "module" is defined by a `Window`, as you suggested, this should work fine - just load them all and show all of their windows.

The one caveat here is that all of the "modules" will be running in one thread, so if one misbehaves (does something that blocks the UI thread) it will block all of the modules.

Comment: And I am also having a problem with switching between windows. Whenever user tries to load same module show/hide the same window, thus using a single instance of each application. But facing problem to get the window in the background to displayed when user tries to launch the application.

Comment: @Satya There's a lot of implementation details here - difficult to help without seeing a small reproducible example.  You should make a separate question for that, with code demonstrating your issues.

Comment: Ok will do that. Thanks.